Can someone explain what signerSize( ) is?
In this contract, I can see that the signerSize is 3. Could someone tell me what that means?

You can refer to line 51 inside the constructor of MultiSig.sol, which shows that signerSize is assigned as the length of the _signers array (i.e., the addresses of signers), and the _signers array is being passed as the first argument in its constructor.
signerSize is also being assigned/updated inside the _setSigner function, depending on the _signer address and the corresponding _active status (i.e., a boolean value) being passed.

thank you so much!

You're welcome. Happy to help!
